# Docker buildx gives exit code: 137 with cargo

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo

I know exit code 137 represents an OOM exception. I raised already my memory to 12 GB allocated to Docker and restarted my computer. I am still getting this error while running `docker buildx`. The regular `docker build` works perfectly. I am on a stock Mac Studio.

This is my failing command:

`docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t test4 .`

Logs:

```
 > [builder 4/4] RUN cargo build --release:
#0 1.882     Updating crates.io index
#0 46.86 Killed
------
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   6 |     COPY . .
   7 |     
   8 | >>> RUN cargo build --release
   9 |     
  10 |     FROM debian:11.5
--------------------
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cargo build --release" did not complete successfully: exit code: 137
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.65.0-bullseye AS builder

WORKDIR app

COPY . .

RUN cargo build --release

FROM debian:11.5
WORKDIR app

COPY --from=builder ./app/target/release/hello ./hello

CMD ["./hello"]
```

It is a hello world program written in Rust.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there was a similar issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10781#issuecomment-1163819998. Using the nightly toolchain and setting the sparse-registry unstable option works.